# Ставить ли тире в предложении "Сумма - 5000 рублей."?

Tags: пунктуация

Ставить ли тире в предложении "Сумма - 5000 рублей."?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если смысл предложения состоит в том, что некоторая ранее оговоренная (напр. требуемая для чего-то) сумма *составляет* 5000 рублей, то тире **нужно**, поскольку оно *замещает* пропущенный и подразумеваемый глагол "составляет":

> Нам нужно найти на это средства. Сумма - 5000 рублей.

Возможны контекстные случаи, когда тире не нужно, например, когда предложение имеет смысл именного указания (типа заголовка, ссылки на запись суммы) и не требует сказуемого:

> Следующая строка поступлений в бюджет. Сумма 5000 рублей. Подумаем, на что её потратить.